# Vuetify Nested List Default Closed?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

https://vuetifyjs.com/ko/components/lists#nested-lists

In this example, I want to make that the "Users" submenu is **closed** for the first time.
I would appreciate it if you could tell me how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `v-list-group` component has a `value` property set to `true`. Change it to `:value="false"`

> You need `:` before 'value`

```
<v-list-group
    prepend-icon="account_circle"
    :value="false"
>
```

This works because the `Users` text is actually sitting inside of the `activator slot`.

```
<template v-slot:activator>
   <v-list-item-title>Users</v-list-item-title>
</template>
```